# In protobuf can I constrain a map's key to certain values?

Tags: java, kotlin, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

So protobuf does not allow string enums to be keys in a map
I want to constrain a map to only have the keys a, b, or c.
I'm working in Kotlin and can use validators like `[(validate.rules).string = {pattern: "^a|b|c$"}]`

```
message payload {
  map<desired_constrained_key_here, string> my_map = 1;
}
```

Can this be done?
How can I do it?
I don't see this in the protobuf docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible; there is no syntax to express that, and no enforcement in any implementation.

However, the following is both possible *and much more efficient*, but requires different usage:

```proto
message payload {
  string a = 1;
  string b = 2;
  string c = 3;
}
```

This is, ultimately, another way of representing a map between the 3 optional keys `a`, `b`, `c` - and a `string` values for each.